# Using d3 to read in information from a CSV file, how can i store values of a particular type into a variable?

Tags: csv, d3.js

I have some code which reads information in from a CSV file. The information is regarding road traffic accidents.

[image]

so with the code, i can target the values using 'd['Weather Conditions']' which gives me -

[image]

which is great! But what i'm actually looking to do is to store values of particular types in variables. e.g so all values equal to 'Fine without high winds' would be stored in an array like object like 'var windy' or something similar, is there anyway i could go about this simply?

*update

some sample data
[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you add a sample of what your data looks like?

Comment: Hi @sparta93, ive added a screen of the data as it appears in the csv? is that enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, in your code, you are simply printing to console each weather condition you encounter as you go over the dataset row by row.

If you want to group your data based on the weather conditions, you can do it using `d3.nest()`.

The example below uses some simple json data to show how you can do it. Here, using `d3.nest()`, we are setting the key to be the weather condition and the values to be the object.

After structuring, your data will be grouped, you can check by running the script below:
All accidents with `rainy` will be under the key `rainy` and the same for all other weather conditions.

```js
var data = [{
  "Weather Condition": "rainy",
  "property1": "val1",
  "property2": "val2"
}, {
  "Weather Condition": "sunny",
  "property1": "val1",
  "property2": "val2"
}, {
  "Weather Condition": "sunny",
  "property1": "val1",
  "property2": "val2"
}];

// put the snippet below in your d3.csv function
var expensesByName = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) {
    return d["Weather Condition"];
  })
  .entries(data);

console.log(expensesByName);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thats great thanks, but is there a way to do it directly from the csv file without further manipulation? i.e converting to JSON. Its a very large data set with thousands of items...

Comment: You don't need to convert anything to `json`. This was just to show you how grouping works and I didnt have any example csv file handy. Simply put the `d3.nest` function inside your `d3.csv` function.